# why i can't print this array with using pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, scanf

i am trying to enter string values (more than 1 for each array) for a1 and a2. I want to print them row by row but the program don't print any of the values. How can i fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void){
int i;
char *a1[10], *a2[10];


for (i=0; i<10;i++){
    printf("Enter text %d for a1", i);              
    scanf("%s",a1);
    printf("Enter text %d for a2", i);
    scanf("%s",a2);
}

for (i=0; i<10;i++){
                    
    printf("text %d is %s for a1",i,a1[i]);
    printf("text %d is %s for a2",i,a2[i]);
}

return 0;


}
```

i tried to print elements of arrray row by row but i cant. Also the program doesn't give an error. Program ending after entering the elements.

Comment: This doesn't even compile as `mevcut` is undefined.  Your program also doesn't make much sense.  The first loop you read two variables but  you are presumably trying to populate a variable.  You say the arrays are char pointers but you read strings (which you need to allocate).

Comment: `a1` and `a2` are arrays of pointers. `%s` expects the argument to be an array of characters. You should be getting a warning from your `scanf()` calls.

Comment: @Barmar Right, I misread the printf format string as the scanf.  Update comment.

Comment: Did you try reading and printing _one_ string? Or an array of `int`? It is always best to start with something simple and get it working perfectly, before you advance to more complexity.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not getting any warnings

Comment: Then you need to increase the warning level. I get `warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat]`

Comment: @Beta yes I did. but I'm having trouble with string arrays

Comment: @AllanWind Am I need to write a1[i] instead of a1 while getting the values in the first loop?

Comment: Yeah, see my answer below.

Comment: @Barmar so how can I enter multiple string values in one array and then print the value I want?

Comment: @AllanWind i tried this but the program just getting first value and ending.

Comment: Allocate memory for `a1[i]` with `malloc()` to hold the strings, and then use `scanf("%s", a1[i])`

Comment: Please direct comments for my answer below.   Otherwise I may not see it.  I provided example output showing the program working so are you sure you used my program as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your program doesn't compile as you never defined mecut.
2. Use constants instead of hard coding magic values.
3. `a1` and `a2` are array of pointers.  You need to allocate space for the strings you want to read in.
4. The two `scanf()` overwrite data into the same variable but you want it be relative to the index.
5. When reading a string with `scanf()` ensure you set the maximum string length to avoid buffer overflow.  Consider using `fgets()`.
6. Check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise your variables might not be initialized.
7. For readability use `\n` in your `printf()`.

Here is working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
#define STR_LEN 99
#define STR(s) STR2(s)
#define STR2(s) #s

int main (void){
    char a1[N][STR_LEN+1];
    char a2[N][STR_LEN+1];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("Enter text %d for a1: ", i);
        if(scanf("%" STR(STR_LEN) "s", &a1[i]) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Enter text %d for a1: ", i);
        if(scanf("%" STR(STR_LEN) "s", &a2[i]) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("text %d is %s for a1\n",i, a1[i]);
        printf("text %d is %s for a2\n",i, a2[i]);
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
$ seq 20 | ./a.out 
Enter text 0 for a1: Enter text 0 for a2: Enter text 1 for a1: Enter text 1 for a2: Enter text 2 for a1: Enter text 2 for a2: Enter text 3 for a1: Enter text 3 for a2: Enter text 4 for a1: Enter text 4 for a2: Enter text 5 for a1: Enter text 5 for a2: Enter text 6 for a1: Enter text 6 for a2: Enter text 7 for a1: Enter text 7 for a2: Enter text 8 for a1: Enter text 8 for a2: Enter text 9 for a1: Enter text 9 for a2: text 0 is 1 for a1
text 0 is 2 for a2
text 1 is 3 for a1
text 1 is 4 for a2
text 2 is 5 for a1
text 2 is 6 for a2
text 3 is 7 for a1
text 3 is 8 for a2
text 4 is 9 for a1
text 4 is 10 for a2
text 5 is 11 for a1
text 5 is 12 for a2
text 6 is 13 for a1
text 6 is 14 for a2
text 7 is 15 for a1
text 7 is 16 for a2
text 8 is 17 for a1
text 8 is 18 for a2
text 9 is 19 for a1
text 9 is 20 for a2
```

Here is a refactored version that uses a couple of functions to reduce duplication.  Also using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` as you may not like how the latter by default reads words opposed to lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10
#define STR_LEN 100

int prompt_str(int index, const char *name, size_t len, char s[len]) {
    printf("Enter text %d for %s: ", index, name);
    if(!fgets(s, len, stdin)) {;
        return 1;
    };
    s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

void print_str(int index, const char *name, const char *s) {
    printf("text %d is %s for %s\n", index, s, name);
}

int main (void){
    char a1[N][STR_LEN];
    char a2[N][STR_LEN];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        if(
            prompt_str(i, "a1", STR_LEN, a1[i]) ||
            prompt_str(i, "a2", STR_LEN, a2[i])
        )
            return 1;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        print_str(i, "a1", a1[i]);
        print_str(i, "a2", a2[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear, but I think you're looking for something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int i;
    char a1[10][256], a2[10][256];

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i += 1 ){
        printf("Enter text %d for a1", i);
        if( 1 != scanf("%255s", a1[i]) ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Enter text %d for a2", i);
        if( 1 != scanf("%255s", a2[i]) ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i += 1 ){
        printf("text %d is %s for a1\n", i, a1[i]);
        printf("text %d is %s for a2\n",i , a2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A few things to note.  If you want to declare your variables as arrays of pointers, you need to allocate space somehow (probably by calling `malloc` and assigning the pointers).  It is probably simpler to use arrays of arrays rather than arrays of pointers.  You *must* *always* *check* the value returned by `scanf`.  You must always put a width modifier on your `s` conversion specifiers.  Using raw `%s` in a `scanf` is no better than `gets`.